# Apply Swig template engine to contents of variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, swig-template

I'm looking for a filter that applies the Swig template engine to the contents of variable.

Suppose I have the following code:

```
var swig = require("swig");

var str = "{{ hello }}";
var hello = "Hello world";
var contents = "{{ str }} {% raw %}{{ str }}{% endraw %}";

contents = swig.render(contents, { locals: { str: str, hello: hello }});
console.log(contents);
```

This will print the following

`{{ hello }} {{ str }}`

But I want it to print the following instead

`Hello world {{ str }}`

Basically, I'm looking for a filter that applies the Swig engine to the contents of the `str` variable again like this:

```
{{ str | render }} {% raw %}{{ str }}{% endraw %}
```

Is this possible with Swig?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Here's the filter:

```
swig.setFilter('render', function (input, l) {
  return swig.render(input, { locals: l });
});
```

Use it in the template as follows:

```
"{{ str | render(_ctx) }} {% raw %}{{ str }}{% endraw %}"
```